# How can I inspect the values of tags during the submit of a form using Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: form-submit, google-chrome-devtools, forms

During a page's "dormant" state, I can inspect the values of any tag by entering its id in Chrome Dev Tools' console tab, like so, e.g. for a tag with the name "BeginDate":

0) Enter "BeginDate" in the console tab
1) Mash the  key

...and I see the whole shebang:

```
<input alt="date-us" data-val="true" data-val-regex="End Date must be in the format &amp;quot;m/d/yyyy&amp;quot;" data-val-regex-pattern="[0-9]*[0-9]/[0-9]*[0-9]/[0-9]{4}" data-val-required="End Date must be in the format &amp;quot;m/d/yyyy&amp;quot;" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" style="width: 164px;" type="text" value="5/14/2013" class="hasDatepicker">
```

So it shows the value, which is the part I'm interested in, is today's date.

What I want to inspect, though, is just what is being passed/posted when the form's Submit button is pressed; I believe this would be, in asp.net, the contents of the Request object, but how can I see these vals using Chrome Dev Tools?

I right-clicked in the console and selected "Log XMLHTTPRequests" and "Preserve log upon navigation" but...are they logged? If so, where are they? I see nothing in the Console tab...

### UPDATE

Thanks to David Ziemann, here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: It should be in the network tab when you send a request.

Comment: Thanks; more specifically, it's in Network.Headers.Form Data. Convert your comment to an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Network tab will show you any network communication. Within that you can select the request and view the headers which should include the form data.

[image: This gives a bit more info into what is being sent]

Comment: Additionally there is a "Preserve Log upon Navigation" option (Chrome v32) which is useful when reviewing page flow or if your pages are using redirection as it retains the full request history.