# php contact form not sending content

Tags: php, forms

I'm building a site in wordpress and usually use the contactform7 plugin to handle forms, but am trying to learn how to set up a form without having to rely on the plugin. I've had success with this recently, but on this latest site my content is being sent to the recipient. I get an email, but none of the values from the form are being sent.

Here's my form (I know I have to also learn about validation/ sanitization, that will be another topic!):

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>sent/" method="POST" class="col-sm-7">
    <input id="name" placeholder="name:" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required></label>
    <input id="email" placeholder="email:" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required> 
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="message:" name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" required></textarea>
    <button id="contact-submit" type="submit" class="btn form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the user presses submit the page redirects to url/sent/ in that file I have this:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name, $email, \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!"); 
?>
```

Now when I get the email in my inbox it shows up like this:

From: , ,
Message:

That's it. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Added note: It seems that when the submit button is pressed and the page redirects, it's pulling a 404, though the url it's redirecting to IS correct, in fact, even if I just refresh the page without changing the url it  drops the 404 and loads the page content. I guess this is why the content is not being sent, but then why is this happening?

Comment: If you can, try to verify using your browser's debug tools that the HTTP request actually contains the variables and they don't get removed by some JavaScript magic. On a side note, setting unfiltered user content in a mail header just begs for the script to be abused by spammers. At least put some formal validation for the e-mail address in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to check for that @Janoszen any advice? Validation / sanitation is next on my list. Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? Most of them can inspect the POST requests they send. [Here's an example with the Chrome developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549934/how-can-i-inspect-the-values-of-tags-during-the-submit-of-a-form-using-chrome-de).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this problem is due to an issue with wordpress. Wordpress does not allow you to use the name="name" - this causes a 404 and the form values are not sent. I changes the name to 'form_name' and it works perfectly now.

Thanks for your help, hope this can help someone else too!

Thanks to Tom Elliot at http://www.webdevdoor.com for the help!
http://www.webdevdoor.com/wordpress/submitting-form-wordpress-redirects-404-page/

Answer (score 0):

You should always check to see if the values are set

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name, $email, \nMessage: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@email.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
     echo "message sent!";
    }else{
        die("Error!");
    }
}else{
    echo "email or name is not set";
}
```

Also try to change your button to `<input type="submit">` even though it might not make a difference.
Other than that the code looks fine

Comment: Thanks @meda this doesn't seem to help and changing the button to an input changes the button text from 'button' (defined in code) to 'submit query' which I don't know how to change.

Comment: I saw your edit, only session can persist after redirect you should link directly to php script in action of the form